# REST API call is unauthorized

Tags: rest, jwt, authorization, unauthorized

I am trying to make a REST API call from my .Net MAUI mobile app.
First I log in, and get a JwtSecurityToken:

```
JwtSecurityToken JwtToken = new JwtSecurityToken(authenticationResult.IdToken);
```

Then I try to use it to make a REST API call:

```
            HttpClient client = new ();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", JwtToken.RawData);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

This gives me an exception

> Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

What is wrong or missing here?

ADDED:

Here is the respose:

```
{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  client-request-id: 162ea393-a9b2-4e6b-9786-d6e18d18afb1
  Date: Sun, 25 Dec 2022 20:42:26 GMT
  request-id: 162ea393-a9b2-4e6b-9786-d6e18d18afb1
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="", authorization_uri="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize", client_id="00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
  X-Android-Received-Millis: 1672000947348
  X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 401
  X-Android-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
  X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1672000947271
  x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Central US","Slice":"E","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"005","RoleInstance":"CH01EPF000051D6"}}
  Content-Type: application/json
}, Trailing Headers:
{
}}
```

Comment: can you post a sampe 401 response in your question?

Comment: @ToreNestenius I added the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing your own API, you can then set this flag to true:

```
.AddJwtBearer(options => 
{
        options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
        ...
```

Then you will see a reason in the response why it failed:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Sun, 02 Aug 2020 11:19:06 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"
```

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: No, I am not developing my own API...